# Adele's treat: "in and out"

Tags: meaning

A link on Drudge this morning to Adele's mishap at the Grammys.  Here is quote which might be
British slang.  Maybe it's the common yank phase indicating a job quickly done. I don't know.
Here is her Twitter quote:

"Because of it though... I'm treating myself to an in n out. So maybe it was worth it."

What is she saying, "in n out".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IN N OUT](http://www.in-n-out.com/) is a hamburger restaurant chain in the western United States. Perhaps she avoids unhealthy hamburgers as a rule to keep up her appearance, but has decided to indulge to cheer herself up or celebrate?

An [ABC news article](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/adele-explains-wrong-grammys-performance/story?id=36970662) states:

> Despite her on-stage troubles, the singer, 27, still had a pretty great night. Because of the snafu, she wrote, she treated herself to a late-night snack at an L.A. standby: In-N-Out Burger

That makes it very clear.

Comment: Lol.  I never would have guessed it.  Ever!  Thanks.

Comment: Her decision to indulge was definitely an attempt to cheer herself up.  She was quite pitchy last night, which was very much extraordinary for her.

Answer (score -3):

In this sentence, I don't think 'in n out' phrase means the **work** that is done quickly. More likely the **intensity** of the work that has to be done quickly. You can buy [Adele tickets](https://ticketselect.co.uk/adele) to see Adele and ask her yourself) That would be a question she would never expect a fan to ask!